# Self and canonical in API output

Tags: api, rest, web-services

Below output I received when I called and API.

```
{
  "createdOn": "2020-08-01T21:17:15.130Z",
  "updatedOn": "2020-08-01T21:17:15.130Z",
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/B183C87E-7067-4BC9-BD9D-5AFA145532F3/dynamicEntities/975F38A1-E1D1-48B1-AF47-B58E9FBB46A3/pushRequests/6D677CD7-F66F-4C23-8E20-EFC067FAB6F4"
    },
    {
      "rel": "canonical",
      "href": "https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/B183C87E-7067-4BC9-BD9D-5AFA145532F3/dynamicEntities/975F38A1-E1D1-48B1-AF47-B58E9FBB46A3/pushRequests/6D677CD7-F66F-4C23-8E20-EFC067FAB6F4"
    }
```

I know  `rel, href` are there because of `HATEOAS`.I am also aware what does `self` mean here.

I am curious to know what is `canonical`? What does it represent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of all the official link relation types, specifically the ones that have been written down as a standard:

https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml

There you will find that `canonical` is defined in [RFC6596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596).

The summary from that document is as follows:

> In regard to the link relation type, "canonical" can be described
> informally as the author's preferred version of a resource.  More
> formally, the canonical link relation specifies the preferred IRI
> from a set of resources that return the context IRI's content in
> duplicated form.  Once specified, applications such as search engines
> can focus processing on the canonical, and references to the context
> (referring) IRI can be updated to reference the target (canonical)
> IRI.